# Codename One:How to make all letters Capital by Default

Tags: codenameone, mobile-application

I want all letters in Capital .when we entering text in text-field after focus lost all worlds of the text-field should became Capitals by default. 
Is there any property in codename one for that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this method "setConstraint".

```
 textField.setConstraint(TextField.INITIAL_CAPS_SENTENCE);
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: How to set it globally for all Textfield

Comment: You can't set it globally. Also I think that what you asked for is really `textField.addActionListener(e -> textField.setText(textField.getText().toUpperCase()));`